# After pulling a Docker from the repository, how to change the images files?

Tags: nginx, docker

I installed a docker image from the registry by doing.

docker pull  paintedfox/nginx-php5

Now I wish to make some changes to this nginx's config files to add some domains. I believe the config files are somehow help inside the dockers image, but where is the image? How can I change these config files?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can run a shell in the image, with:

```
docker run -t -i --entrypoint bash paintedfox/nginx-php5
```

Then change the configuration files as you like. Note the container ID (it appears in the prompt, e.g. `root@9ffa2bafe2bb:/#`), then commit it to a new image:

```
docker commit 9ffa2bafe2bb my-new-nginx
```

You can then run the new image (`my-new-nginx`).

Comment: can you tell me what should I do with an image that doesn't have bash and is only based on python, like "akhmetov/python-telegram"?

Comment: @LordST I inspected that image, and it comes with busybox. So I was able to do `docker run -t -i --entrypoint sh akhmetov/python-telegram` to obtain a shell. If it hadn't come with busybox, I could have built an image based on it, and adding busybox. I hope this helps!

Comment: @jpetazzp, I realized what should I do, by reading its Dockerfile and after that, I do what I want. I`m thankful for your hints and help.